# Navigation bar search view

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a navigationbar in navigationbarcontroller which is connected to my table view.

Now for a nice design I have the search bar in the navigation controller, and then above the navigation controller, I'd like to have a button on each side.

But I have a problem. An image of the problem is below as well as the code. I'd like to move the search bar below the side buttons and not beside them.

[image: The problem]

```
    let searchbar = UISearchBar()
    searchbar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchbar.placeholder = "Search any Product"
    searchbar.delegate = self

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchbar
```

Comment: what mean of `move the search bar below the side buttons and not beside them. `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the searchbar in the headerview of the tableview. This way you also have easy ways of hiding the searchbar.

Below is the link for a small tutorial which shows how to do it, ofc you can customize the color and stuff but this is the basic setup.

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift